# Read Strings from command line util one can be 'read' as a Float

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write code that will prompt the user to enter a Float and will continue to do so until a valid float is entered.

I've tried the following approach:

```
getFloat :: Float
getFloat = do 
    input <- getLine
    case (readMaybe input :: Maybe Float) of Just f -> f
                                             Nothing -> do getFloat
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Main.hs:41:5:
    Couldn't match type `IO b0' with `Float'
    Expected type: IO String -> (String -> IO b0) -> Float
      Actual type: IO String -> (String -> IO b0) -> IO b0
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: input <- getLine
    In the expression:
      do { input <- getLine;
           case (readMaybe input :: Maybe Float) of {
             Just f -> f
             Nothing -> do { ... } } }
    In an equation for `getFloat':
        getFloat
          = do { input <- getLine;
                 case (readMaybe input :: Maybe Float) of {
                   Just f -> f
                   Nothing -> ... } }

Main.hs:42:56:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `Float'
    In the expression: f
    In a case alternative: Just f -> f

Main.hs:43:60:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `Float'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: getFloat
    In the expression: do { getFloat }
```

I'm a beginner a would very much appreciate if someone could explain what am I missing here.

Comment: Look at the type of `getLine`. Is it `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getFloat :: Float
```

This states that `getFloat` is a constant of type `Float`, which is not what you want.

```
getFloat :: IO Float
```

This instead states that `getFloat` is an IO action producing a `Float`.

Once this is fixed, then you need to add `return` in front of your `f`, as @ErikR already explained. The return turns the pure float value `f` into an IO action which produces it, without actually performing any IO.

Finally, you do not need the `do` in the last `do getFLoat`. The `do` syntax is useful to sequence IO actions: if you only have one, it is redundant.

Comment: So there's no way to produce a `Float` from a function that does IO ? And I will always be forced to drag that IO Float with me until I use a `<-` ?

Comment: @HarryM Briefly put, yes. The main idea is that if a function does some IO, this _has_ to be reflected on its type. There are some helpers to adapt standard functions to work on IO, for convenience. E.g. `cos getFloat` is a type error, `do f <- getFloat ; return (cos f)` is OK but verbose, `cos <$> getFloat` is equivalent and much more concise. Try reading a monad/applicative tutorial for these shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

For the Just case, use `-> return f` instead of `-> f`.

And then just remove the type signature for `getFloat`. After it compiles, have ghci tell you what the type signature for `getFloat` is.

Complete code:

```
getFloat = do
    input <- getLine
    case (readMaybe input :: Maybe Float) of Just f -> return f
                                             Nothing -> do getFloat
```

**Update**

You might be interested in this highly-polymorphic version of the loop:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.Read

getItem = do
  input <- getLine
  case readMaybe input of
    Nothing -> getItem
    Just x  -> return x
```

I have purposely written `getItem` without a type signature - this is something that GHC can infer and fill in for you. I've also used the NoMonomorphismRestriction pragma so that `getItem` remains polymorphic.

The idea is that `getItem` can be used for any type that can be read - Floats, Doubles, Strings, etc. The type used by `readMaybe` can be controlled by the caller in various ways. Here are some examples:

```
main = do
  f1 <- getItem
  f2 <- getItem
  let r = f1 + f2 :: Float
  print r
```

By forcing `r` to be type Float, `f1` and `f2` must also be Floats, and therefore `getItem` will try to parse a Float.

Here is another way to influence the type that `readMaybe` uses:

```
main = do
  f <- getItem :: IO Float
  i <- getItem :: IO Int
  print $ f^i  -- compute f raised to the i-th power
```